# Swift's #selector statement seems not to terminate correctly in SO syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Looking at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007862/575530) the syntax highlighting for Swift's `#selector` statement seems not to terminate correctly.

(N.B. I tried editing the answer to include `<!-- language: lang-swift -->` but that did not help.)

At first I assumed that this was a problem with the underlying prettifier, but [it appears not](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/439).

Can the Swift extension be added to Stack Overflow's copy of Prettify so that the code will be rendered correctly?